# adding ruby and sass to path in maven ant-run exec task

Tags: ruby, maven, ant, sass, gruntjs

I'm trying to get grunt to work in a maven ant-run task. I've already added /usr/local/bin to my path in the ant-run task, but the process fails on my sass-dist grunt task, stating that ruby and sass needs to be on my classpath.

So after adding `~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/` to the path I expected it to work, but it doesn't.

I'm also using the 1.6 version of the plugin since I'm stuck at maven 2.0.10, 1.7 requires 2.0.11

Below you'll find my ant-run task

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <target name="building">
                            <echo>
                                ---------------------------------------------------
                            </echo>
                            <echo>
                                NPM INSTALL
                            </echo>
                            <echo>
                                ---------------------------------------------------
                            </echo>
                            <exec executable="npm" dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp"
                                  osfamily="windows" failonerror="true">
                                <arg value="install"/>
                            </exec>
                            <exec executable="/usr/local/bin/npm" dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp"
                                  osfamily="unix" failonerror="true">
                                <env key="PATH" path="${env.PATH}:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin"/>
                                <arg value="install"/>
                            </exec>
                            <echo>
                                ---------------------------------------------------
                            </echo>
                            <echo>
                                GRUNT
                            </echo>
                            <echo>
                                ---------------------------------------------------
                            </echo>
                            <exec executable="/usr/local/bin/grunt" dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp"
                                  osfamily="windows" resultproperty="cmdresult">
                            </exec>
                            <exec executable="/usr/local/bin/grunt" dir="${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp"
                                  osfamily="unix" resultproperty="cmdresult">
                                <env key="PATH" path="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/"/>
                                <arg value="production" />
                            </exec>
                        </target>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Are you sure the '~' is being expanded correctly?  What if you fill in the actual directory '~' represents instead?  If that's not it, you may have to add ruby to the plugin classpath (by specifying it as a plugin dependency).

Comment: even with adding /users/username/ instead of ~ it doesn't do the trick, so I've created a shell script that does the same thing and ran it with the maven exec plugin